# Cython files not getting compiled by gcc compiler

Tags: python, c++, c, gcc, cython

I tried to convert a python script into cython file using the command-

```
cython --embed -o front.c front.py
```

Then i tried to compile using gcc compiler with the following command-

```
gcc -c front.c -I\C:\Users\Akhil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\include\
```

I am getting the following error saying that Python.h file not found.

```
front.c:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I have verified that Python.h is present in the python directory. what could be the reason for not compiling the cython file? Do i have to follow any extra commands to get it compiled?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about what your Windows port of `gcc` expects, but my first guess would be that it doesn't like the backslash preceding the drive letter in your path.  At least, that's not Windows convention.

Comment: So, what should i put there instead of backslash?

Comment: @AkhilReddy a double backslash `\\`

Comment: You can use forward slashes.  BTW, don't include a backslash after `-I`.